# Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open session

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to insert one transaction with multiple product  as shown below in addTrasction method ,there are one to many relationship between transaction and product class ,but this error appears  Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

this is hibernate cofigurtion

```
  File path2Config= new File("./src/com/config/hibernate.cfg.xml"); 
  SessionFactory sessionfactory=new       
  Configuration().configure(path2Config).buildSessionFactory();
  Session session=sessionfactory.openSession();
```

save product method

```
public Product save(Product product){
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(product);
session.getTransaction().commit();
return product;
 }
```

save transaction metho

```
public Transaction save(Transaction transaction){
   session.beginTransaction();
session.save(transaction);
session.getTransaction().commit();
return transaction;
 }
```

addTransaction method

```
public void addTrasction(Product product){
    Transaction transaction=new Transaction();

    for(Cart c:list){
        product=new Product();
        product.setProductName(c.getProductName());
        product.setProductPrize(c.getPrize());
        product.setQuantity(c.getQuantity());
        product.setTransaction(transaction);
       product=productDao.save(product);
    }
    Date transactionDate=new Date();
    transaction.setTransactionDate(transactionDate);
    transactionDao.save(transaction);
     }
```

transaction class

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="transaction")
  public class Transaction {
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="autoGen" ,strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="autoGen")
@Column(name="transactionId")
private long transactionId;
@Column(name="transactionDate")
private Date transactionDate;
@Column(name="cost")
private double cost;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="transaction")
private List<Product> products=new ArrayList<Product>();

public Transaction()
{   
}
public long getTransactionId() {
    return transactionId;
}
public void setTransactionId(long transactionId) {
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
}
public Date getTransactionDate() {
    return transactionDate;
}
public void setTransactionDate(Date transactionDate) {
    this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
}
public double getCost() {
    return cost;
}
public void setCost(double cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}
public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}
public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

    }
```

product class

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="Product")
    public class Product {
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="autoGen" ,strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="autoGen")
@Column(name="productId")
private long productId;
@Column(name="productName")
private String productName;
@Column(name="productPrize")
private double productPrize;
@Column(name="quantity")
private int quantity;
@JoinColumn(name = "transactionId")
   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Transaction transaction;
public long getProductId() {
    return productId;
}
public void setProductId(long productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}
public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}
public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}
public double getProductPrize() {
    return productPrize;
}
public void setProductPrize(double productPrize) {
    this.productPrize = productPrize;
}
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public Transaction getTransaction() {
    return transaction;
}
public void setTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    this.transaction = transaction;
}


   }
```

Comment: Try to use getCurrentSession() instead of openSession()

Comment: I did but session close  error appear

Comment: The problem is that you open(and close) 2nd session inside another one . Session are bounded to the thread. When you used getCurrentSession() you took the first session, but now you're trying to close it 2 times.

Comment: Hibernate autimaticaly will save the Product when you save the Transaction. Try to remove `product=productDao.save(product);` from addTrasction method.

Comment: Thanks for replay I removed it,but product not saved

Comment: If the relation is bidirectional(Transaction class has a collection of Product-s) you need to add the product to the collection in the Transaction class. If you post the hibernate mapping of the two classes it will be helpful.

Comment: I added the product and transaction classes

Answer (score 0):

Replace `addTrasction` method with

```
public void addTrasction(Product product){
    Transaction transaction=new Transaction();

    for(Cart c:list){
        product=new Product();
        product.setProductName(c.getProductName());
        product.setProductPrize(c.getPrize());
        product.setQuantity(c.getQuantity());
        product.setTransaction(transaction);
       transaction.getProducts().add(product);//here is the change
    }
    Date transactionDate=new Date();
    transaction.setTransactionDate(transactionDate);
    transactionDao.save(transaction);
   }
```

That way hibernate will execute one insert in the transaction table and as many as needed in product table with the right FK.

Comment: The field Transaction.products is not visible

Comment: public void addTrasction(Product product){
  Transaction transaction=new Transaction();
  Date transactionDate=new Date();
  transaction.setTransactionDate(transactionDate);
  for(Cart c:list){
   product=new Product();
   product.setProductName(c.getProductName());
   product.setProductPrize(c.getPrize());
   product.setQuantity(c.getQuantity());
   product.setTransaction(transaction);
     product=productDao.save(product);
  }
  
              }

Comment: the previous code runs when insert one product but when add more session closed

Comment: My mistake(too much c#). You need to use the getter(`transaction.getProducts().add(product);`). Answer edited.

Comment: I did but the method just insert to transaction ,Did you check the previous code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it

change sessionfactory.getCurrentSession to sessionfactory.openSession and change addTrasction method to

```
public void addTrasction(Product product){
    Transaction transaction=new Transaction();
    Date transactionDate=new Date();
    transaction.setTransactionDate(transactionDate);
    for(Cart c:list){
        product=new Product();
        product.setProductName(c.getProductName());
        product.setProductPrize(c.getPrize());
        product.setQuantity(c.getQuantity());
        product.setTransaction(transaction);
        product=productDao.save(product);
    }
    list.clear();
```

}